# How should I store images for my website/app?

Tags: c#, html, .net

My team and I (all students, this is a college project) are creating a software, that's basically 2 frontends (a website and an app) connected to a backend through an API. We have the entity user in this software, and one of its properties its `image` since we expect to have a lot of users, We don't think storing the images directly on the database it's the best thing.

So in this kind of cases what should we do ? What's the best practice ? (all the components are going to be deployed so local storing it's not really an option).

(We had in mind to get some 3rd party service where we could upload the images and just store the link in the DB, but is this possible? is this fine?).

Comment: The best way IMHO is to store the link in the DB and that way as you said image can be stored either on 3rd party like Amazon S3 or on your disk.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using cloud storage like

- Amazon S3 (https://aws.amazon.com/s3/)
- Google Cloud Bucket (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets)
- Microsoft Azure Storage (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-introduction)

They have some free of charge for experiments/learnings but you also need to be aware of charge fees after some certain usages limits. They're using cloud computing, so you don't need to worry about the performance.

Another choice that you can build your own image server and serve images directly to your website. The benefits could be

- Having the same connection directly to your website via domains (faster than cloud sometimes)
- You can flexibly control your image sizes/types according to your image requests. For example, you can convert your images to WebP or compress them to fit users' local devices
  Of course, with this way, you need to have knowledge about building an image server.

Answer (score 0):

there are many different cloud storage services that you can use to host images for your project. most popular of them is [**imgbb**](https://api.imgbb.com) & [**imgur**](https://api.imgur.com) . I've been using them for a long time and they work great. Both have api's which are very simple to implement. If its your first time using them, you might want to watch a tutorial on [**youtube**](https://yt.be) . Hopefully this helped you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).